# LabelBinarizer encodes majority class as 1 instead of 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

My train data has a majority class of negative samples and a minority class of positives samples. I use LabelBinarizer() to transform the text labels to binary and want the positive samples to be encoded to 1 and the negative to 0. I read that by default the majority class should get encoded to 0 however I observe the opposite.

```
Y_train = ['normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'malware']
lb = LabelBinarizer()
Y_train= np.array([number[0] for number in lb.fit_transform(Y_train)])
print Y_train.tolist()
```

The outcome I get is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I expected:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Can someone point out the mistake? Thanks

**Update:**

According to https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6723,

> the positive label is given to the class with the greater value (i.e.
>   later in lexicographical sort order).

This explains the encoding in my case. However, I will still want 'malware' to be encoded as 1 and 'normal' as 0. Guess I have to do it manually ?

Comment: Where did you read `majority class should get encoded to 0`? It seems which class comes first in the list of labels gets `0`. You can try it.

Comment: Here:https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6723 It would also make sense to me as normally majority samples are negative in many applications

Comment: thanks, was just looking at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html

Comment: yes. there is no mention of what is considered negative and what as positive. Should be defined.

Comment: Strange running exact code I get `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`. What is the version of sklearn?

Comment: Was the order of classes same as my OP? Check my update. It seems that encoding is alphabetical order based.

Comment: Ran same above code and pasted the output. so, its same as expected in above.

Comment: you are correct. I made a mistake copying the code. The outcome I get is based on last label of "malware" not "virus". As "m" comes before "n" of normal so "malware" gets an encoding of 0

Comment: I think what you are looking for can be done using `label_binarize` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize. **Note** that `classes` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be done by using [label_binarize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
Y_train = ['normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'malware']
# note the order of "classes" defines which gets 1 and which gets 0
Y_train = label_binarize(Y_train, classes = ['normal', 'malware']).flatten()
```